# Hyperbolic growth, deriving from hyperbolic functions

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

When a quantity grows towards infinity in a finite-time, it is said to undergo hyperbolic growth. An example being a quantity that every time it doubles, the growth rate itself also doubles.

Normally this is modeled on the graph of 1/x (Wikipedia - hyperbolic growth). What I don't understand is why this phenomenon is called "Hyperbolic"? Is there someway that this could be formulated in terms of the hyperbolic functions? Or even the hyperbola curve?

Thanks.

Comment: Define "Hyperbolic Growth phenomenon".

Comment: Re-worded following Wikipedia - hyperbolic growth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve $y=1/x$ is a... hyperbola.

Comment: I think that's right. Thanks.